# How do I set the IP range for Scapy Sniff filter?

Tags: python, ip, scapy, bpf

I try to do the below filter in my Sniff function:

```
pkt = sniff(count=1, iface='Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter', filter='host 178.0.0.0/8')
try:
    print(str(pkt[0][1].src)+'-->'+str(pkt[0][1].dst)+":::"+str(pkt[0][3].load))
except:
    pass
```

But this filter do not work, instead, the code prints the traffic to all hosts and not the 178.0.0.0/24

Comment: Do you want `178.0.0.0/8` or `178.0.0.0/24`? Your code and comment are at odds.

Comment: my apologies, I want 178.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your filter is compiled by the libpcap, `host` does not work with CIDR blocks (network + mask). It takes a name or an IP address (v4 or v6).

Instead you want to use `net`:

```py
... filter='net 178.0.0.0/8')
```